# can a custom spinner adapter take a arraylist as parameter

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I hold some bundles in arraylists of arraylists `'ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();'`

This leads to an issue with the super method in the constructor. It doesnt like anything outher than objects or lists passed to it.

Can I use arrayList or must i cast it to object or list?

```
    public class Game_AddFixtures_SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fixtureDetails = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        private Context c;
        public Game_AddFixtures_SpinnerAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> objectList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objectList); //ERROR HERE
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.c = context;
            this.list =objectList;
        }
}
```

error:

> cannot resolve method 'super(android.content.context, int,
>   java.util.arraylist>)

Comment: yes easily you can pass, use  extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>>

Comment: You'll be needing to override the `getView()` as well, otherwise you'll face weird errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes can take, just change this in your code

`public class Game_AddFixtures_SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>>`

The reason here is `super` `constructor` is looking for `String` in the argument ,but you are passing `ArrayList<String>`. You need to extend `ArrayList<String>` to pass `List` of `ArrayList`.

Hope this clears the thing..

Comment: Can you point me towards some doc that explains the 'super)...) method to me, this worked, i'd like to understand why

Comment: Yes its basically a `Core Java` concept/thing.. You can find many resources explaining `super()` in a general context. Just try searching for "How does super() work in java" and you will have your answers :)